# Maven. Как собрать .jar без ресурсов внутри

Tags: java, maven, jar, сборка

Подскажите, как собрать jar'ник без папки /resources и при этом указать в конфиге maven'a, чтобы он создавал данную папку в директории с самим jar'ником?

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html

Comment: @Suvitruf Благодарю. А как указать, что <exclude> файлы должны находиться в другой конкретной директории?